# Resolving Moment.js Deprecation Warning in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, date, momentjs

I am getting an warning for the following code, using moment.js, in my Angular app:

```
moment(value).add(6, 'hours').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

The warning/error printing to the console is:

> moment.js:293 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a
>   recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js
>   Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non
>   RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an
>   upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments:  [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false,
>   _l: undefined, _i: Apr 10, 2007, 10:00:00 PM, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

I have looked at the documentation page linked in the warning, but it's still unclear to me what I need to change to get rid of the deprecation warning. I tried, for instance, adding an empty array as a second argument:

```
moment(value, []).add(6, 'hours').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

...but while that gets rids of the error, I get "invalid date" printed in my view, instead of the actual date. How do I need to adjust the syntax here to get rid of the warning?

UPDATE: The value being provided is a UTC value that has been transformed using the Angular date pipe. So I am passing through two pipes: first the Angular date pipe, and then this custom pipe using moment. the full pipe code looks like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
const moment = require('moment');

@Pipe({name: 'timeZoneSync'})
export class TimeZoneSyncPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor() { }

    transform(value) {
        if (value) {
            return moment(value).add(6, 'hours').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        }
    }
}
```

And in my view I am using the two pipes like this:

```
  <input class="app-input" [ngModel]="client.dob | timeZoneSync | date:'medium'"
                                (ngModelChange)="client.dob=$event" name="inputField" type="text" />
```

Comment: looks like the date `value` you provide to moment is not under the ISO or RFC2822 format.

Comment: What is `value`? Can you share that, seems like that's where the issue is

Comment: The value being provided is a UTC value that has been transformed using the Angular date pipe. So I am passing through two pipes: first the Angular date pipe, and then this custom pipe using moment.

Comment: Show us an exact example of the date value passed to moment.js please

Comment: What exactly has surprised you? `date:'medium'` does not produce either of the required formats. Why are you even using it; why take a date then format it to a string *then parse it back to a date **then format it to a string again?***

Comment: @jonsharpe To answer your question, I want the date in a reader-friendly format. So the date pipe takes 1981-09-24T05:00:00.000Z and gives me a user friendly format. But then I use moment to add hours to the date to resolve timezone sync issues.

Comment: *"to resolve timezone sync issues"* - now this seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), because just adding a fixed offset isn't how  to deal with localising datetimes. The accepted answer doesn't solve that problem; look into e.g. [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). And yes, it is exasperating to see someone apparently ignore the error message they've posted and not think through what the code they've written actually does; if nothing else, because that's precisely what you're *supposed* to do as part of creating a [mcve]. Also SO will autocomplete my actual username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a link in your error message. It indirectly leads you to this: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407

**Quote**:

> moment construction using a non-iso string is deprecated. What this means is you can safely do
>
> > moment("2014-04-25T01:32:21.196Z");  // iso string, utc timezone
> >
> > moment("2014-04-25T01:32:21.196+0600");  // iso string with timezone
> >
> > moment("2014 04 25", "YYYY MM DD"); // string with format
>
> but you can't do reliably (therefore its being deprecated)
>
> > moment("2014/04/25");
> >
> > moment("Thu Apr 24 2014 12:32:21 GMT-0700 (PDT)");
> >
> > moment("some random string that looks like date");

Basically, whatever provides the value to your `TimeZoneSyncPipe` is not doing a good job making sure that the date is in the `ISO` or `RFC2822` format.

**More specifically**

`'mediumDate'` argument is equivalent to `'MMM d, y'` (e.g. `Jun 15, 2015`) which is not even close to ISO.

**FIX**

Try using something like `"client.dob | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ' | timeZoneSync"`

**Forest behind the trees**

@jonrsharpe  is very right! My answer explains the "why" you see the error. But Jon asks a better question. Why keep translating `date` -> `string` -> `date`!?

**Example**

```
const parsedDate = moment("1981-09-24T05:00:00.000Z");
console.log(parsedDate.format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4jo4n8idrem7T1hqytU8?p=preview)

[image]

Comment: It's doing a fine job of what the OP asked, which was **not** either of those formats.

Comment: I want the date in a reader-friendly format. So the date pipe takes 1981-09-24T05:00:00.000Z and gives me a user friendly format to display in the view. But then I use moment to add hours to the date to resolve timezone sync issues.

Comment: @Ademo you may want to do things in a different order then: `client.dob | timeZoneSync | date:'medium'`, which is: first, correct the `date`; second, translate it into a string. In fact, you will be able to throw away `.format("MM/DD/YYYY")` in your `timeZoneSync` pipe then.

Comment: Thanks, I just had the same thought. Working on changing the order now.

Comment: No, it should work fine with the date you provided in the example. At least this is how I think things should work, based my interpretation of this code https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/create/from-string.js#L222

Comment: So, actually, since our database provides the values like this: "dob": "1981-04-24T05:00:00.000Z", that's going to prompt this warning regardless, right? So the issue is not with the Angular date pipe. Is there any way to hide the warning? - because I don't think I'll be able to change the way we store dates on the backend.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko - I get the same warning, even after taking out the date pipe. So if the issue is the value that's being provided, then it doesn't like this format: 1981-04-24T05:00:00.000Z

Comment: @Ademo your DB dates must be wrong. I can't repro what you are saying: https://plnkr.co/edit/4jo4n8idrem7T1hqytU8?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "wrong". This is a copy and paste directly from the db document: "dob": "1981-04-24T05:00:00.000Z". So, for some reason, it doesn't like this format.

Comment: See my plunkr. Things should work. Your date string must get modified somewhere before it gets to the pipe. Put a breakpoint in your Pipe's code and see what you actually get there. There are no miracles.

Comment: There may be no miracles in code, but there is basic logic.

Comment: @Ademo Sorry, nobody will be able to help until you open a _new_ question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because I have answered your question and showed a plunkr that verifies my answer. Your question though is starting getting updates that invalidate my answer. Put `console.log(value)` right before `return moment(value)....`  and look into  your browser console. I bet the logged value is not what you're showing us.

Comment: A combination of what you suggested, and making another tweak to my code -- including taking out the Angular pipe altogether, because it's actually redundant here -- has now resolved my issue.